# EISDIR - EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform

When I try to upload an image into a bucket on the server side I'm getting the error above. I checked using the debugger that the file parameter contains the file's path and not the folder's path. Here's the code :

```js
function uploadFile(file, directory) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            const bucket = storage.bucket(BUCKET_NAME);
            const bucketFile = bucket.file(directory ? `${directory}/${file.originalname}` : file.originalname);
            const blobStream = bucketFile.createWriteStream();

            blobStream.on('error', err => {
                const status = err.status || 500;
                console.log(err, status);
                reject(err);
            });

            blobStream.on('finish', async () => {
                // The public URL can be used to directly access the file via HTTP.
                await bucketFile.makePublic();
                const publicUrl = `https://storage.googleapis.com/${bucket.name}/${bucketFile.name}`;
                resolve(publicUrl);
            });

            blobStream.end(file.buffer);
        } catch (err) {
            reject(err);
        }
    });
}
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Run it with `strace` to see which exact syscall causes the `EISDIR` and what its path argument was - or, if you get a stack trace, add some log output directly at the `fs` call which causes the error. Then based on what you find, think about how that can be - I can't say without knowing what you found first. :)

Comment: The error hints on you reaching a directory instead of a file in your bucket, so I would log the values of `directory` and `file.originalname` to check if they are correct, could you do that and share this information?

Answer (score 3):

The path of the file was right. But the path to the credentials was wrong